# Shouldn't there be a name-agnostic class pointer similar to 'this' pointer for member functions to refer to in C++?

Tags: python, c++, class, this

In Python, there's a `self` variable that refers to the instance itself, and a `cls` object (for class methods) that refer to the class. In the same manner, there's a 'this' pointer pointing to the calling object; but I'm not aware of any pointer to the class itself, I'm familiar with using something like this...

`ClassName::memberFunction(this)`

But it's not what I want.

I guess it's pretty obvious that there's no such thing, given how constructors still make use of their class's name, but why not make it a feature in C++?

Comment: Sadly, no. Are you trying to make a macro or something?

Comment: In C++ classes doesn't exist in that way. A class or structure is really nothing more than a way to group functions and variables.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: C++ is not (yet) a reflective language. Aside from `decltype(*this)` which yields a reference to the static type, there's not much you can really do.

Comment: In Python, classes are values. It's not so in C++; a class doesn't exist at runtime.

Comment: Features usually make their way into C++ by being useful in a variety of situations and mixing well with a variety of existing features. How does this idea fare in this test? I'd say it gets a pretty weak score. Not that many situations, and virtually no interaction with existing features.

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock I was trying to call a thread on a member function `threaded_func` from within another member function, and I just didn't want to mention the class's name 
`thread(&Mandelbrot::threaded_func, this, x_range, y_range)`

Comment: @StoryTeller Noted, thanks.

Comment: @isados: We tend to use lambda's for that: `[=]{threaded_func(x_range, y_range);}`

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have this kind of keyword allowing something like:

```
class C
{
    Self(const Self&) = default;  // Not valid
    ~Self() = default; // Not valid
};
```

You could simulate it with MACRO:

```
class C
{
#define Self C
    Self(const Self&) = default;
    ~Self() = default;
#undef Self
};
```

> but why not make it a feature in C++?

You can still try to create a proposal for that.

Whereas using it in class definition seems fine,
using it outside seems problematic:

```
C::C(const C&) {} // Regular way

Self::Self(const Self&) {} // Which class ?
C::Self(const Self&) {}    // Mix C and Self
```

Comment: Why a macro? `using Self = C;` obeys the language rules, and sidesteps some of the problems you show below. `Self::Self` of course can never work.

Comment: @MSalters: `struct C {using Self = C;
    Self(const Self&) = default;};` is still wrong :-/ `C(const Self&) = default;` is, but mixing too. `using` might be enough for user case though.

Answer (score 1):

> but I'm not aware of any pointer to the class itself

A class is not an object, so there can not be a pointer to a class.

Within other member functions (i.e. the only places you may have access to `this` in the first place), you can refer to static member functions simply by their name:

```
struct S {
    static void foo(){}
    void bar() {
        foo();
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah pointer was the wrong word.. I meant a way to resolve the type of the enclosing class that @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a method of the class, the tokens

```
std::decay_t<decltype(*this)>
```

will evaluate to the type name of `this`.

Outside of a method there is no similar technique.

It isn't in the language, because nobody has gotten such a feature through the committee.  It would take work.

A number of compilers have extensions that resolve to the "parent class".  I'm unaware of a compiler that has the extension for "type of enclosing class".